# Polymer attributes and variable mapping

Tags: html, polymer

I have a polymer element looking like this:

```
<polymer-element name="foo" attributes="bar">
<template>
<core-ajax
url="url.php"
params="{{ {last: bar} }}"></core-ajax>
{{bar}}
</template>
</polymer-element>
```

Though, when I create element, the attribute shows up on the page, but  the ajax request is like `url.php?last` so it seems that variable is undefined. 
Also, this.bar returns undefined.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind core-ajax has been deprecated in polymer 1.0 to iron-ajax.

Anyway, is params bind being resolved properly?

Based on [documentation for new iron-ajax element](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) the sintax should be:

> params='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'